# How can I find all Powered by the Apocalypse questions?

Tags: support, game-systems, search

There are dozens of Powered by the Apocalypse questions out there, and they're all similar enough that it's conceivable a [Tremelus question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99604/how-do-i-handle-a-situation-that-doesnt-have-a-player-facing-move) could be duped to a [Dungeon World](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/what-do-you-do-in-dungeon-world-when-someone-wants-to-perform-an-action-they-don) one.

So, if I'm looking for advice on a PbtA game that doesn't have any questions asked here yet, but for which generic PbtA guidance still applies, how could I find those questions?

There is a [powered-by-the-apocalypse](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powered-by-the-apocalypse) tag, but the questions under it are not of high value to my scenario relative to the game-specific questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Search.

`[sagas-of-the-icelanders] or [tremulus] or [apocalypse-world] or [dungeon-world] or [the-sprawl] or [powered-by-the-apocalypse] or [monsterhearts] or [monster-of-the-week] is:question` should do the trick. (Results of that search [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsagas-of-the-icelanders%5D+or+%5Btremulus%5D+or+%5Bapocalypse-world%5D+or+%5Bdungeon-world%5D+or+%5Bthe-sprawl%5D+or+%5Bpowered-by-the-apocalypse%5D+or+%5Bmonsterhearts%5D+or+%5Bmonster-of-the-week%5D+is%3Aquestion).)

`[foo]` in the search bar specifies a tag; "or" works as you might presume

`is:question` limits the return to question-posts.

---

That list of tags was generated from [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/677697), helpfully created by [@Miniman](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/15469/miniman?tab=profile). It only finds tags whose description mention being powered by the apocalypse. (If you find some tags missing this in their description, please edit it in! It'll improve the site and your ability to find them... win-win!)

Comment: It's certainly by no means comprehensive - for example, it doesn't pick up the [tag:powered-by-the-apocalypse] tag, since it's missing a tag wiki.

Comment: Searching tag wiki *excerpts* catches [tag:powered-by-the-apocalypse] and [tag:monsterhearts].

Comment: hmm... wonder why it's not picking up [tag:monster-of-the-week]?

Comment: It did, I just wasn't paying attention.

Comment: Since it's had all this work anyway, you might as well have [the better query](http://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/677697).

Comment: @Miniman excepts worked better only cause whoever made them didn't understand how tag wiki's v.s. excerpts work.  The matter has been corrected.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Luckily, the query I called the better query searches both excerpts and their wikis :)

Comment: [Tag:Masks-a-new-generation] is also PBA

Comment: As are [tag:urban-shadows] and [tag:urban-shadows-2e]